# Firebase realtime database blocked by CORS policy: react js app issue. Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm executing a simple delete command to remove one of my toDos in my toDoList react app and I get the response the response that `XMLHTTPRequest` to my url is blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy and AxiosError returns me a network error

Access to `XMLHttpRequest` at 'url' from origin `http://localhost:3000` has been blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I have checked yt axios tutorials and they don't have this issue. Some solutions I found online is to make a backend with  `Access-Control-Allow- Origin` response header on my domain which I don't really understand because I am still learning backend.

Any tips on fixing the problem without having to set up a backend or a link to a tutorial on setting pu a backend with my react app would be appreciated.

```js
const deleteHandler = async (id) => {
    try {
      console.log(id)
      await axios.delete(
        `{url}.json/${id}`
      );
      const toDoList = toDos.filter((toDo) => toDo.id !== id);
      setToDos(toDoList);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

I tried to find solutions to fix the problem but so far nothing worked and i am really stuck. I found a stackoverflow question to oxforddictionary problem that's the same as mine but i don't know how to apply it to my firebaes database.